# Как правильно реализовать если есть на странице кнопка то клик , а если нет идем дальше!

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

Есть кнопочка которая двигает контент вправо. Когда мало контента — её нет, когда много контента — она есть.

Реализовал следующим образом (сам метод - очень долго отрабатывает, больше минуты (когда нет той самой кнопки), но работает! Когда есть, логично работает быстро):

```
public boolean clickContentUnderPlayer() {
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

 try {
     if( clickRight.isDisplayed()){
         clickRight.click();
         return true;
     }
 }

 catch (Exception e)  {
        return false;
 }

return false;
}
```

Наверное, проблема с ожиданием. Очень долго ищет элемент на странице. 
Подскажите, как правильно реализовать, или иной способ реализации.

Comment: А на каком именно месте работает больше  минуты? Из кода видно, что заходит один раз и возвращает значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> очень долго отрабатывает, больше минуты (когда нет той самой кнопки), но работает!

Скорее всего указано ожидание при создании экземпляра драйвера.
Чтобы не ловить эксепшн каждый раз, когда элемента нет - лучше проверять его наличие через  проверку `driver.findElements(By.xpath("elementXpath")).size()>0`